# what does "keep it covered" mean when police uses it?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm watching the tv show "The Equalizer". In this show, there's a hostage situation at the bank. and police car arrived. Police got out of cars and looking at the bank. Then yelling.

1. I have a second floor up.
2. Keep it covered!

and I didn't understand both of these sentence. They didn't say it to each other, these are separate lines.

I guessed it as

1. I have eyes on second floor? or I'm in charge of second floor? or I saw someone(criminal) on second floor?
2. hide your body behind something so you don't get shot? or you should take charge in certain place?(door or window)

They don't have any context beyond this, because scene just got started and end. I heard second one a lot from cop movies and tv shows but I don't know what it means.

Comment: Do you have a link to a clip of this moment? That may help us better understand what context these phrases being used in.

Comment: No, unfortunately I tried to find a clip but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of "covered" is [definition 6 here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cover): to keep your attention, and probably gun, trained on a person or thing to be ready to take action.

I'm not sure about the first sentence; I expected another noun after "a" (like "I've got a sniper, second floor up." Regardless, "I've got a" can often mean "I have spotted a ___."

Comment: [A famous story from the 1992 LA riots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_Los_Angeles_riots#Day_5_%E2%80%93_Sunday,_May_3): "Cover me!" was interpreted differently by the police and Marines as "fire if necessary" (the meaning you note here) and "fire liberally" (i.e., lay down covering fire), respectively.